# Create an array in excel from an access table field

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create an array in excel vba from an access table field. The table has 4 fields, but what I need is to create an array that contains only data from field 2. I did the connection to access, then I use this code to fill the array:

```
Array1 = Array(Rs.Fields(1).Value)
```

But Array1 only loads 1 item from field 2 and I don't know how can I make the loop to load all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use dynamic arrays, and move the recordset in a loop.

```
Dim array1() As Variant
Do Until Rs.EOF
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve array1(1 To n)
    array1(n) = Rs.Fields(1).Value
    Rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The method of getting the entire recordset as an array is as follows, but the rows and columns are transposed.

```
array1 = Rs.GetRows
```